# Jquery tablesorter cannot disable column sort

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm using jquery plugin table sorter trying to disable sorting on a column. I have tried:

```
data-sorter="false" //not working
class="{ sorter: false }" // not working
class="sorter-false" // not working
```

You can see here a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZJINXSTBnsyd1sGpE1Ut?p=preview

Comment: All of the options you shared above work in my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), but not all work with the original, maybe that is where this confusion is coming from? The `class="{ sorter: false }"` only works if you have the metadata plugin loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following as a parameter to the table order worked for me with your code:

```
$( '.dirf_tbl' ).tablesorter({

    headers: {
      // disable sorting of the first column (we start counting at zero)
      0: {
        // disable it by setting the property sorter to false
        sorter: false
      }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Your solution work, but I prefer to use class method. However it seems that the download zip has an old repository,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `headers` [**option**](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-options-headers.html):

```
function tblSortOn(){
    $( '.dirf_tbl' ).addClass( 'tablesorter' );

    $(".dirf_tbl").tablesorter({ 
        // pass the headers argument and assing a object 
        headers: { 
            // assign the secound column (we start counting zero) 
            1: { 
                // disable it by setting the property sorter to false 
                sorter: false 
            }, 
            // assign the third column (we start counting zero) 
            2: { 
                // disable it by setting the property sorter to false 
                sorter: false 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

In this case, your `Last Name` and `Age` will be disabled.

**[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/totxUnjTnhVA2SxkMssM?p=preview)**

Comment: As said on previous comment, I think that an old vrsion is zipped in the download. If I copy/paste the code used on example site it works great.